# Suggest the best noSQL database for AJAX based application (i.e no Websockets )

Tags: javascript, firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

Recently I created a project using **Firebase, CloudFirestore (i.e Not their realtime DB )** I used to pull date every 3 seconds using **AJAX** polling and JS setInterval, but as a free user I ran out of request and my app stopped working, can anybody suggest me any solution on the cloud that is free, or should I use **mongoDB** or something ?

Answer (score -1):

For Cloud noSQL solution you can use [Google Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/) which has a [free quota](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/pricing). If your usage is inside of the free quota limits, you can use it without any charges.